# how many items can i fit in my box

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a cuboid with a width of 500mm, a height of 500mm and a length of 1000mm.

I need to know how many 38mm balls i will need to fill the cuboid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Three questions: (1) is 38mm the radius? (2) what have you tried so far? (3) is this a homework problem? I also took off the measure-theory tag since that wasn't the right way to classify this problem.

Comment: radius is 38mm (its a sphere) the answer i have at the moment is 4394, but i am not sure if this is correct. Sorry i couldn't find a correct tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i am not wrong the total numbers of balls will be "4394"

```
  26 balls length wise
```

{
 1000/38= 26(approx)
}

13 balls width wise
{
 500/38= 13(approx)
}

and 13 height wise 
{
500/38= 13(approx)
}
which will lead you to 26*13*13 = 4394 balls (approx)

Comment: This assumes square packing, which is easily shown to be sub-optimal, at least for infinite packing. How small the grid has to be for this to take effect, I do not know.

Comment: thats the answer i had, thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @danyo
no Problem :)

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_close_pack) says if you just pour the spheres into the box you will achieve a density of $0.609$ to $0.625$, leading to $5299$ to $5438$.  If you shake the box it will be $0.625$ to $0.641$, or $5438$ to $5577$ balls.  If you pack them perfectly (and ignoring the edge effects) you get $0.7401$ for $6439$ balls.  All are much better than cubic packing.